# Amazon MWS PHP Client library include path errors when executed in cron

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, autoload, amazon-mws

So I have a working code that works flawless when I call the URL directly in the browser. However when I setup the same file in cron, it causes the class not found errors. I believe the set_include_path function is causing the errors.

I modified the file paths without any luck. Here is how the .config.inc.php looks like.

```
 set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts');

     function __autoload($className){
        $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
        foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
            if(file_exists($includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
                require_once $filePath;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding `dirname(__FILE__)` in front of the $filepath variable as well as before the actual folder MarketplaceWebServiceProducts in set_include_path() function. but no luck.

And here is my cron command

```
php -q /home4/username/example.com/_manager/a/_data_ru/getASINData.php
```

The php client library is located in /_data_ru/ folder.

Can someone guide me to the right direction what I need to do to make it work in cron as well?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
cd /home4/username/example.com/_manager/a/_data_ru && php -q getASINData.php
```

You're using relative paths, so result will depend from which place your script is executed. You should use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (with [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) if you need a parent directory) to make this more predictable:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts');
```